# How do you post request authenticated in Qt to django rest framework with BasicAuthentication?

Tags: python, django, qt

I want to send data through a post request but only those who are authenticated can do it. In django application I added the BasicAuthentication in **settings.py**

```
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    )
}
```

and in Qt post authenticated to do so

```
...
QNetworkRequest request;
QUrl url("https://.../data/");
url.setUserInfo("username:password");
request.setUrl(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
QString json = QString(...);
QNetworkReply *reply = m_manager->post(request, json.toUtf8());
...
```

As an error the server returns me -> **Error transferring https://username:password@.../data/ - server replied: Bad Request**.

I can not understand whether the problem lies in the way in which pass username: password or django app.

Answer (score 0):

Set user info just appends the "username:password" to the URL authority section. See the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurl.html#setUserInfo) for an example. For HTTP basic authentication, you need to use something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1700751/2628463).